# How to fetch data in View in Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I have to fetch MySQL data in view in Laravel 4.2.

Not from the controller or routes.
I come to view from controller.
Now I need to fetch data from MySQL again.

I know it is a bad practice.
But I really need that badly.
Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok you know it already, but I'm gonna say it one more time. The view is not supposed to do such things. However it is possible. You can fetch data like you would in a controller. Preferable using an Eloquent Model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution for that.

In view blade file write something like

```
$pic=DB::table('car_picture')->select('car_picture_link')->Where('car_id','=',$value->car_id)->take(1)->get();
foreach ($pic as $key => $p_val) 
{
    $car_pic = $p_val->car_picture_link;
}
```

It will solve the problem.

But it is not recomanded.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to access any class from anywhere in Laravel. But it is not recommended to use it in view directly. As Laravel is MVC framework. So it will break programming methodology. If your application is small and your just in development mode you can use it directly.